# Why is this hyperlink taking the whole table cell and not just on the text?

Tags: html, asp.net, .net, html-table, cufon

Facts:

- I'm working under Visual Studio .NET 2008
- I'm using Cufon-yui.js as a font replacement tool.
- The link is inside of a Table `<td>` (as it handle much more info)

The command I use is:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="thisistheID" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">
  <h3 style="width:250px;">Title of the Link</h3>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

In Firefox and IE, I'd like to mouse over the text and have the link there, solely. If I mouse over the whole cell (of the table) the link is available and appears there even tho I don't have letters there.

How can I have this link to work just where the letters are?

I hope I asked this question the appropriate way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you turn it inside-out?

```
<h3 style="width:250px;">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="thisistheID" runat="server" NavigateUrl="#">
        Title of the Link
    </asp:HyperLink>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are making the h3 tag a link. Two ways to fix it if this is the case....

a. Style the asp:HyperLink and don't specify the width (no need for h3 tag unless you are doing some javascript stuff for it).

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
   Font-Bold="True" 
   Font-Size="Large"
   text="Title of the Link" 
   NavigateUrl="default.aspx" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

b. Use plain old html mark up inside the h3 tag if you don't need to access the control server side:

```
<h3 style="font-size: larger">
   <a href="Default.aspx">Title of the Link</a> 
</h3>
```

Comment: I gave it a width, to see if that could solve the width of the link. This link is using whitespace to the right, and uses the complete cell. Let me use your solutions and I'll keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: The solution from the user egrunin worked a little better.  But still, I think the problem is Cufon-yui.js   Also it flickrs a bit while rendering when I load the page.